# Passing parameters from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the typical HTML "contact me" page, i.e. name, e-mail address and message. Since I want to do input validation on the page itself using JavaScript, I can't use a `submit` button, otherwise, the attached JavaScript function would be ignored. At least that's how I understand it, CMIIW.
I tried to load the next page writing `location = mail.php` but it appears that the form parameters don't get passed to my PHP page this way.
How do I validate input in JavaScript and pass parameters to my PHP page when ok?
TIA
Steven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the onSubmit event.  Attach it to your form and if it returns true then your form will be sent to the PHP page.  Read more [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html).

Comment: Accepted for being first and to the point, even though scompt was too lazy to spell the solution out. But I can understand that; it's a hot day. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a form with an onsubmit handler on it, that returns false if the validation failed. If the check is ok, return true and the form will submit normally.

You'd have a javascript function something like this:

```
function check_it_all() { 
  if (all_ok) {
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}
```

And the form

```
<form action=.....  onsubmit="return check_it_all();">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should still use the submit button to submit the form, that is the correct behavior.

Input validation should be done using the `<FORM>`'s `onSubmit` event.
It should look something like this:

```
<script>
    function validate() {
        var isFormValid = whatever; // validate form
        return isFormValid;
    }
</script>

<form action="your.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <!---fields--->
</form>
```

Comment: You need to capture the return value of the validate method in your onsubmit handler.

Answer (score 1):

The function `validate()` returns a `bool`.
This will stop the submission if `validate()` returns false.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="click" />
```

I am an `aspx.net` developer so I am used to putting the validation call on the button.

Answer (score -2):

If possible can't you use a JavaScript library like Jquery? It probably would make your life alot easier and they have tons of plug-ins for validation.

Such as

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/